# Create textboxs with for loop in VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am creating multiple textbox with for loop in VB.net, the textbox will show value from array, but when i run  it return wrong value, like this:

> Y

> S

> T

> E

> M

How can i fix it? Here is my script. Thank you.

```
Dim nameTextbox() As String = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}
    For i = 1 To nameTextbox.Length
        Dim textbox As New Windows.Forms.TextBox()
        textbox.Text = nameTextbox.ToString(i)
        textbox.Name = nameTextbox.ToString
        textbox.Size = New Size(225, 25)
        textbox.Location = New Point(70, 10 + 25 * (i - 1))

        Me.Controls.Add(textbox)
    Next
```

Comment: `textbox.Text = textbox.ToString(i)` <-- I suspect you want `textbox.Text = nameTextbox(i)` instead.

Comment: `For i = 1 To nameTextbox.Length` <-- You need to start at `0`, not `1`. VB.NET's arrays are zero-based: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/

Comment: `textbox.Name = NomLabel.ToString` <-- This might cause issues too, because you're giving every new `TextBox` the same `.Name` property, but WinForms controls' names should be unique within their container, otherwise `Controls.Find` won't work.

Comment: `textbox.Text = nameTextbox(i)` It gave me an error when i run it. @Dai

Comment: @TuanDo Please note that `nameTextbox.ToString` has a value of "System.String[]". I guess you wanted `textbox.Name = nameTextbox.ToString(i)`. (But something like `textbox.Name = "tb" & i` might be more sensible.)

Comment: In addition to what Dai commented, the loop should be `For i = 0 To nameTextbox.Length - 1`.

Comment: One more thing, If i want these textboxs show different text that are not from the array. Can I do that?

Comment: @TuanDo Oops, I meant I guess you wanted `textbox.Name = nameTextbox(i)`.

Comment: I'd modify @Dai 's comment slightly to say that indexing in .NET is customarily zero-based.  It's possible (though not straightforward) to create arrays with other lower-bounds, but such things won't play nicely with any of the conventions of the built-in class library.  (Insert rant about 1-based being better than 0-based here; I "grew up" on VB3, VBA-heritage VB, and Fortran, all of which customarily use the correct indexing.)

Comment: @Craig Methinks I'll just [point you towards Djikstra's brief paper on that subject](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html).

Comment: Which I will concede makes sense in the context of how the C-heritage languages manage upper bounds (and, really, also in the context of a `Do` or `While` loop in VB) but not in the context of how VB (and Fortran) manage bounds in a counted loop, where the natural representation is 1 .. n, not 0 .. n-1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
Dim nameTextbox() As String = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}
    For i = 0 To nameTextbox.Length - 1
        Dim textbox As New Windows.Forms.TextBox()
        textbox.Text = nameTextbox(i)
        textbox.Name = nameTextbox.ToString(i)
        textbox.Size = New Size(225, 25)
        textbox.Location = New Point(70, 10 + 25 * (i))

        Me.Controls.Add(textbox)
    Next
```

Comment: please provide at least a bit of explanation in addition to the code